# Singly Linked List Reversal using Double pointer and Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I tried reversing a linked list using a pointer-to-pointer to the head node being used as a parameter in the function below :

```
void reverseLLRec(Node** start) {
    Node* curr;
    // Empty list
    if (*start == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    curr = *start;
    if (curr->link == NULL) {
        *start = curr;
        return;
    }
    
    reverseLLRec(&(curr->link));
    curr->link->link = curr;
    curr->link = NULL;
}
```

I'm getting the following output -

[image]

It seems like the `*start` pointer is not getting modified to point to the new head.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you alter `curr->link` by passing its address to the recursive call, the next use of `curr->link` is no longer referencing the node you intended.

You should not let the recursive call alter `curr->link`. On the other hand, you *should* alter `*start`, since that has to refer to the new head (after reversal). So pass *that* address to the recursive call.

So replace this line:

```
reverseLLRec(&(curr->link));
```

with these two lines:

```
*start = curr->link;
reverseLLRec(start);
```